Were the Filipino cardinal elector(s) from the "Conclave" book also in the film adaptation?
In the 2024 film adaptation of Conclave, which depicts the College of Cardinals of the Catholic Church convening to elect a new pope, a notable change was made to the key character of Cardinal Benitez. Originally a Filipino cardinal elector in the 2016 novel, he is portrayed as Mexican in the film. Watching the movie, I didn't notice any cardinal electors from the Philippines, but I might have overlooked them.
This question came to mind because, to my knowledge, the Philippines is one of only two Catholic-majority countries in Asia (the other being Timor-Leste, also in Southeast Asia). The Philippines' significant Catholic population and its cardinal electors in real life likely influenced the book's portrayal of Benitez as Filipino.
It seems fitting to include representatives from the Philippines for added realism and to align with the book's narrative. Were there any cardinal electors from the Philippines in the film, and if so, who were they?
